# $\ker f$ is either dense or closed when $f$ is a linear functional on a normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $f$ be a linear functional on a normed linear space $X$. Prove that $\ker f$ is either dense or closed in $X$.

Two possibilities can occur, i.e either $f$ is bounded or unbounded. If it is bounded then $f$ is continuous and hence $\ker f=f^{-1}(0)$ which is closed

How to show when $f$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is unbounded. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\to0$ and $f(x_n)=1$ for all $n$.

Now choose any $y\in X$. Then $y-f(y)x_n$ is in $\ker f$, since $$f(y-f(y)x_n)=f(y)-f(y)=0.$$ Thus $y=\lim_n y-f(y)x_n$, where the elements in the sequence $\{y-f(y)x_n\}$ are in $\ker f$. So $\ker f$ is dense in $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a non-trivial linear functional on $X$, and let $\mathcal{N}(f)$ be the null space of $f$. There exists $y \in X$ such that $f(y)=1$ because $f$ is non-trivial. Therefore,
$$
               x = f(x)y + (x-f(x)y) \in [\{y\}]+\mathcal{N}(f), \;\;\;(\dagger)
$$
where $[\{y\}]$ is the one-dimensional linear space spanned by $y$. Hence $X/\mathcal{N}(f)$ is one-dimensional, and the quotient map is
$$
                      x \mapsto f(x)y + \mathcal{N}(f).
$$
If $\mathcal{N}(f)^{c}$ denotes the norm closure of $\mathcal{N}(f)$, then it follows that either $\mathcal{N}(f)^{c}=\mathcal{N}(f)$ or $\mathcal{N}(f)^{c}=X$. If $\mathcal{N}(f)^{c}=\mathcal{N}(f)$, then $X/\mathcal{N}(f)$ is a normed space, and the quotient map from $X$ to $X/\mathcal{N}(f)$ is continuous in norm, and this map agrees with $f$ because $x\mapsto f(x)y$ under this quotient map, because of $(\dagger)$. So $f$ is continuous if $\mathcal{N}(f)$ is closed. Conversely, if $f$ is continuous, then $\mathcal{N}(f)=f^{-1}\{0\}$ is closed. If $f$ is not continuous then $\mathcal{N}(f)^{c}=X$, which means that $\mathcal{N}(f)$ is a dense subspace of $f$ in $X$.

Comment: When you take the norm closure of the kernel $\mathcal{N}(f)$, how can you assert it is either closed or dense, but not "nowhere dense and not closed"? It seems, at that point, you only know the kernel is a proper subspace, and nothing more.

Comment: @user760 : $\mathcal{N}(f)$ has co-dimension $1$ in $X$. If you add any element to $\mathcal{N}(f)$ that was not already in $\mathcal{N}(f)$, then you get $X$. So, the closure of $\mathcal{N}(f)$ is either $\mathcal{N}(f)$ or it is $X$. There is no subspace strictly between $\mathcal{N}(f)$ and $X$. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!

Comment: @user760 : You are welcome!

Comment: Then when the functional is discontinuous, the kernel is also codimension-1. And that extra dimension can be approximated by elements in the kernel. Also all the elements not in the kernel lie in this extra dimension. That means the kernel kind of "wraps up" around this extra dimension from all directions, but not intersecting with it. Cool!