# Is the quotient space of a vector space with a dense subspace isomorphic to the underlying field?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces, dense-subspaces

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field, $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-Banach space and $U<V$ be a dense subspace (with $\overline{U}=V$). I have heard, that:
$$V/U\cong\mathbb{K}.$$
Is this result even correct and if not, what is a simple counterexample? If it is, how do you prove it? Unfortunately, it looks a lot like it can simply be done with the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms, but that is not the case. There is no surjective function $f\colon V\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{K}$ with $\ker(f)=U\Rightarrow f\vert_U=0$ since the latter condition combined with $U$ being dense implies $f=0$.

Comment: This is not true. You can [construct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496436/construct-dense-subspace-of-codimension-n-for-all-n) a dense subspace with large codinension. What is true is that if $V$ has codim one [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517382/in-a-topological-vector-space-a-subspace-of-codimension-1-is-either-dense-or-cl) it is either dense or closed.

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty similar and is also correct. Looks like the theorem got a bit falsified by being told around.

Comment: When you're thinking about dense subspaces in functional analysis I think it can be helpful to think of these as a subspace that can "approximate" the whole space well. For example, the polynomials are dense in $C[0, 1]$ by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, which is a very nice example of a dense subspace. But there is no way that this quotient will be one-dimensional - the polynomials are far too small of a subspace.

Comment: Density of a subspace $U$ of a topological vector space $V$ is characterized by the condition that the quotient topology on $V/U$ is trivial, i.e., the only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $V/U$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Why not an official answer?